# Share a file into Email from externalStorage directory

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

How can I send a file from external storage directory location like `/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.abc.myApp/files/AppLog/Logs/28032022.txt'` via email. When user clicked on Upload button it'll open email app with attached file. *I've to upload single or multiple files from this **Logs** directory. How could I do something what I say here*

```
ElevatedButton.icon(
onPressed: (() async {
  url = 'mailto:${''}?subject=Subject&body=$AttachedFile';
  launch(url);
}),
icon: Icon(Icons.restore_sharp),
label: Text("Upload Log")
)
```

In AttachedFile I have to pass the file/path

Comment: I see no upload buttn. Where?

Comment: I've updated my code snippet. Please have a look. Basically I've to pass file path into url so that email will launch with the attached file(in my opinion, may be it'll be done some other way)

Comment: Where can i see that button? And what is wrong with your code?

Comment: The button is in a page where user send mail with attached log file. I can pass string value inside body. But can't send a .txt file as attachment for mail body.

Comment: What I need is to attach a file with mail body. How could I achieve that?

Comment: You only use &subject and &body. Those indeed are not for attachments. Look further.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243378/discussion-between-pasha-and-blackapps).

Answer (score 1):

- ## First Solation

This will add a line like this to your package's `pubspec.yaml`

`mailto: ^2.0.0`

`url_launcher: ^6.0.3`

define the `email-send-mail.dart` class and use this code.

```
import 'package:mailto/mailto.dart';
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';

launchMailto() async {
  final mailtoLink = Mailto(
    to: ['mr.mirshahbazi@gmail.com'],
    cc: ['xyz@gmail.com', 'zyx@gmail.com'],
    subject: 'mailto example subject',
    body: 'mailto example body',
  );
  // Convert the Mailto instance into a string.
  // Use either Dart's string interpolation
  // or the toString() method.
  await launch('$mailtoLink');
}
```

#### Note: you must convert your `28032022.txt` to string and put it in the body.

- ## Secend Solation

This will add a line like this to your package's `pubspec.yaml`

`flutter_email_sender: ^5.1.0`

define the `email-send-mail.dart` class and use this code.

```
import 'package:flutter_email_sender/flutter_email_sender.dart';

Future<void> sendemail(
    {required List<String> to,
    String subject = "",
    String body = "",
    required List<String> cc,
    required List<String> bcc,
    List<String>? attachmentPaths,
    bool isHTML = false}) async {
  final Email email = Email(
    recipients: to,
    cc: cc,
    bcc: bcc,
    subject: subject,
    body: body,
    attachmentPaths: attachmentPaths,
    isHTML: isHTML,
  );
  await FlutterEmailSender.send(email);
}
```

Comment: But I can't attach any attachment.Later, I've solved this by using ``flutter_email_sender: ^5.1.0`` package.

Answer (score 0):

Solved the issue by using flutter_email_sender package. Just have to call **_sendMailWithAttachment()** inside Upload button.
Package: *flutter_email_sender: ^5.1.0*

```
  Future <void> _sendMailWithAttachment() async {
    // give your file path
    final directory = await getExternalStorageDirectory();
    var attachment = File(directory).path;
    final Email email = Email(
      body: '',
      subject: '',
      recipients: [''],
      attachmentPaths: [attachment],
      isHTML: false,
    );
    await FlutterEmailSender.send(email);
  }
```